# How to find middle point given angle and 2 other points?

Tags: geometry

The question is:
The lines L and M have equations y = 2x + 3 and 2x + y = 11 respectively.  Point A has co - ordinates (1, 5).

As part of the question, I found a) the intersection of L and M is P(2, 7) and b) that the equation of a line passing through A that is perpendicular to M is y = 1/2x + 9/2.

The last part is "B is a point on M such that ABP = 90 degrees.  Find the co-ordinates of point B."  I could do this if it didn't have to be on M, but I am not sure how to bring M into it.

All help appreciated.

Comment: The line through B and P is just line M. So the line through AB is perpendicular to M. Is has slope = ?? and you know the coordinates of one point already. You should be able to solve for the equation. Have you drawn a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it thanks to Chaz.

As said, the line through B and P is the line M, which can be checked by substitution.  If looking for a right-angle, then AB must be perpendicular to M.  Invert the gradient of M to get 1/2, and find the y-intercept by subbing in the point A to get 4.5.  So the line AB is y = 1/2x + 4.5.  This means that y can be replaced by 11-2x (which is M re-arranged), to get the final co-ordinate B of (2.6, 5.8).

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks correct when drawn.